# Check an array contains an object using one key with Array.includes

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an Array, like this one:

```js
let myarr = [
  {type:"a", class:"x", value:"p"},
  {type:"b", class:"x", value:"r"},
  {type:"a", class:"y", value:"p"}
];
```

I need to use `Array.includes` to check whether an object with `class=y` is in this array.

I need to check it with `myarr.includes({condition});`

I could simply compare the whole object but I don't know how to use a key of the object to check.

Comment: it does not work with `includes`. you need a different approach. why `includes`?

Comment: Why are you using .includes() for that? Is this a requirement?

Comment: Why would you *need to check it with `myarr.includes`*? Thats not the right method for the job

Comment: `myarr.some(x=>x.class=='y')`??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To do this you can use the [`some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) method.

> The some() method tests whether at least one element in the array passes the test implemented by the provided function.

```js
let myarr = [
  {type: "a",class: "x",value: "p"},
  {type: "b",class: "x",value: "r"},
  {type: "a",class: "y",value: "p"}
];

let pass = myarr.some(item => item.class == 'y');
let fail = myarr.some(item => item.class == 'z');

console.log(pass);
console.log(fail);
```

Answer (score 2):

`Array.prototype.includes` relies on identity checks which requires you to pass in the same object (not just an object with the same properties, it needs the same reference such that `objA === objB`). You want a function that allows you to provide a function in which you can check the condition. Fortunately there is `Array.prototype.some` for this ask.

```
myarr.some(item => item.class === 'y')
```

Answer (score 1):

You may either use `Array#some` or you may also take advantage of using proper data structures.

### Array#some

```js
const myArr = [{
    type: "a",
    class: "x",
    value: "p"
  },
  {
    type: "b",
    class: "x",
    value: "r"
  },
  {
    type: "a",
    class: "y",
    value: "p"
  }
]

const hasClassY = myArr.some (o => o.class == 'y')
console.log (hasClassY)
```

### `Map` instead of `Array`

```js
const classMap = new Map([
  ['x', [{
    type: "a",
    class: "x",
    value: "p",

  }, {
    type: "b",
    class: "x",
    value: "r"
  }]],

  ['y', [{
    type: "a",
    class: "y",
    value: "p"
  }]]
])

if (classMap.has('y')) {
  // Do stuff here
}

const itemsWithYClass = classMap.get('y')
const itemsWithXClass = classMap.get('x')

const flatten = xs => [...xs].reduce((r, el) => [...r, ...el])

const allItems = flatten(classMap.values())

console.log('Y class: ', itemsWithYClass)
console.log('X class: ', itemsWithXClass)
console.log('All: ', allItems)
```

#### Specialized `Map`

```js
class SpecializedMap extends Map {
  get[Symbol.species]() {
    return Map
  }

  getAll() {
    return [...this.values()].reduce((r, el) => [...r, ...el])
  }
}


const classMap = new SpecializedMap([
  ['x', [{
    type: "a",
    class: "x",
    value: "p",

  }, {
    type: "b",
    class: "x",
    value: "r"
  }]],

  ['y', [{
    type: "a",
    class: "y",
    value: "p"
  }]]
])

if (classMap.has('y')) {
  // Do stuff here
}

const itemsWithYClass = classMap.get('y')
const itemsWithXClass = classMap.get('x')
const allItems = classMap.getAll()


console.log('Y class: ', itemsWithYClass)
console.log('X class: ', itemsWithXClass)
console.log('All: ', allItems)
```

### Array + Set

```js
const myArr = [{
    type: "a",
    class: "x",
    value: "p"
  },
  {
    type: "b",
    class: "x",
    value: "r"
  },
  {
    type: "a",
    class: "y",
    value: "p"
  }
]

// This set contains all unique classes within myArr
// The challenge is you need to sync myArr with classSet
// so classSet contains the actual classes within myArr.
const classSet = new Set(['x', 'y'])

// Somewhere in your code you import classSet and...

if (classSet.has('y')) {
  console.log('Do stuff here!')
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this simple solution.

```js
let myarr = [
  {type:"a", class:"x", value:"p"},
  {type:"b", class:"x", value:"r"},
  {type:"a", class:"y", value:"p"}
];

console.log(myarr.some(function(element){return element["class"] === "x";}))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Array.prototype.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) or [String.prototype.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) but is not practical, and is not useful as a general solution in this case, see this:

```js
let myarr = [
    {type:"a", class:"x", value:"p"},
    {type:"b", class:"x", value:"r"},
    {type:"a", class:"y", value:"p"}
  ];

//String.includes - We need the exact match, this could lead to error  
var value1 = JSON.stringify(myarr).includes('"class":"x"');

//Array.includes - It's ok, but it has two iterations, not one as some()
var value2 = myarr.map(o=>o.class).includes("x")

console.log(value1)
console.log(value2)
```

That is why using `Some()`, as other users said, is the better choice.

Answer (score -2):

I use lodash .includes() or .has() methods for things like that:

```
_.includes({ 'a': 1, 'b': 2 }, 1);
```

https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#includes

You can also do this with a plain js map, some or other methods.

Comment: Generally, unless the OP specifies otherwise, it's best to avoid needing a library in your answer. A good way to improve this answer would be to acknowledge `some()` and then add lodash as a suggestion after the fact.

Comment: @AndrewBone ye, i understand, but its still nothing wrong to know, u can do it fast with lodash. Cause sometimes u have  "2 mins" (not 2 hours looking for plain js solutions) to push changes:)